# Is there an issue with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, voting

Very shortly (less than a minute) after I posted this question:

[How can I import multiple items from a module and rename them in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865421/how-can-i-import-multiple-items-from-a-module-and-rename-them-in-python)

it received 2 downvotes. No comments (I know, I'm just as bad...). However, I'm not sure what is wrong with this question?

It is a self answer, so I may be looking at it wrong, but it doesn't appear to be a non-question.

If it is off topic I'll happily flag for closure etc, but I'd like to know if there is an issue with it, and if it can be fixed...

Comment: It's a poorly asked, and more importantly, low researched question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In what way? I searched for quite a while, and I still haven't found anything that solves it, other than very indirectly, and I searched for at least 15 minutes before realising the solution... How would you suggest I edit it to improve?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons that people could have for downvoting, and we can't really read their minds. However, part of your problem may be that a lot of people, for whatever reason, see self-answered questions as "cheating."

Comment: @AstroCB Well then those people need to read this post http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ because they are catagorically wrong.

Comment: I'm not one of these people, to clarify. I meant the question per se reads low researched (given there's a python syntax reference). I didn't even spot you self answered it at the 1st glance.

Comment: No, if it is bad without the answer it is bad. How would you suggest I show that I have researched it?

Comment: Also note that by asking about the question here, you've invited the Meta effect, which can have some unintended (and unexplainable) consequences.

Comment: @AstroCB Yeah, I know :/ I'd kinda rather my Meta question wasn't downvoted - or is that bad as well...? It seems to be a valid question for here... Evidently SO people are very different to elsewhere.

Comment: I don't really understand the down-voting of meta questions when someone is trying to get feedback and improve how they use the site - do people doing it feel it's a lack of research, or something else? That said, I've noticed in a few cases recently there's been a burst of down votes, followed by up-votes from people who felt it was a positive sign that someone was asking how to improve, so they do sometimes get turned around.

Comment: You'll run a considerable risk of attracting RTFM votes with a question like that.  It is already well explained in [the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import_stmt).  Maybe you can rescue it by linking to the manual and spending a few words on how the syntax notation works, in case that was the hang-up.

Comment: Maybe if you rephrase your answer as if you had just solved it, it would lessen downvotes from people who downvote self answered questions

Comment: @JoDouglass [Downvotes on Meta indicate disagreement.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) Whether that applies to this specific question remains unclear, but if anything, the downvotes here are likely in disagreement with the complaint being made.

Comment: @AstroCB I'm not referring to cases where there's a complaint being made, just those where a user asks for feedback on how to improve a specific post or their posts in general. I understand that votes here can indicate disagreement, but I don't understand people disagreeing with someone asking how they can improve their post quality.

Comment: @JoDouglass That's what I meant by the fact that the reasoning "remains unclear"; you can't choose between parts of the post to vote on, however, and the complaint being made here is inseparable from the request for help improving the OP's question.

Comment: @AstroCB I'm not trying to complain...

Comment: @Tim I understand that, but the fact that you're asking for help implies a disagreement with the voting that's occurring, which is inevitably linked to a complaint when you post on Meta. That's just a guess, though – there's no way to know what people are thinking when they downvote unless they comment, and they are not bound to do so.

Comment: @AstroCB I wonder if you've (indirectly) answered my question. I don't see a complaint in this post, just a person asking for guidance - his complaint was only made in the comments *after* a number of downvotes happened. But perhaps some people tend to read these questions as complaints regardless and feel people shouldn't be complaining, whereas I tend to read them as positive requests for help improving unless they specifically involve a complaint as well.

Comment: @AstroCB Ahh I see, yes good point. I have to say, I would dv some posts like this on Ask Ubuntu (although ones that were complaining more so). I tried to be neutral in this one...

Comment: @JoDouglass I don't see it that way myself, but a lot of people I've talked to do, and that's really what I was hinting at.

Comment: @Tim Anyway, the question has improved. Personally, I don't think you should have to make up an excuse for a self-answered question (although that's often common due to the reasons stated above), but I don't want to remove it because that's your decision to make.